# C++ eigen library: what is best practice to write a function that applies coefficient-wise math operation and works for ArrayBase and MatrixBase?

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

idea 1: write one function with `DenseBase` parameter
signature: `template <Derived> void foo(DenseBase<Derived> param)`
within function body: `param.derived().array()`

idea 2: write two functions, one with `ArrayBase` parameter, the other with `MatrixBase` parameter
function A signature: `template <Derived> void foo(ArrayBase<Derived> param)`
within function A body: no need of creating an `ArrayWrapper`
function B signature: `template <Derived> void foo(MatrixBase<Derived> param)`
within function B body: `param.array()`

These are my two ideas for writing a function that applies coefficient-wise math operations and works for `ArrayBase` as well as `MatrixBase.`What do you think is the better one? Is there another best practice?

-------------------

Comment: Make sure to never use `DenseBase<Derived> param`, etc by value (I would have guessed that this does not even compile, except for very old Eigen versions). But using `DenseBase` and `.array()` is fine.

Comment: @chtz: Thanks for the hint! Yes, I was sloppy here and should have passed by reference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the first approach is that the `ArrayBase` class doesn't offer an `.array()` method, so you need some kind of distinction here. Since C++17, however, you can do that in one function using `if constexpr`.

This, you can write one function with a `DenseBase` parameter, and treat the two cases differently. You can introduce another lambda in order to avoid code duplication:

```
template<typename Derived>
auto cwise_transform(DenseBase<Derived> const& dense)
{
    auto trans = [](auto const& m) { return m.abs(); };  //abs as example

    if constexpr(std::is_base_of_v<MatrixBase<Derived>, Derived>)
    {
          return trans(dense.array());
    }
    else
    {
          return trans(dense);        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yet, the ArrayBase class actually offers an array() method and the MatrixBase class also offers an matrix() method. They are not listed in the documentation but I have already used them.

Comment: @miguelditoo: ok, I was looking in the reference documentation. In general, if it is not listed there, I would be reluctant to use it, however for Eigen and your code it is likely ok to use it. And yes, if both classes offer an `array()` method, just write one function as in your alternative 1.